# Scale text labels to plot features in r

Tags: r, text, plot, label

I have the following plot:

```
xleft<-c(1,2,2.5)
xright<-c(2,2.5,2.75)
ybottom<-c(1,2,2.5)
ytop<-c(2,2.5,2.75)

par(mar = c(15,15,2.75,2.75) + 0.1)
plot(c(1,2.75),c(1,2.75),type="n",main="title",xlab="site.x",ylab="ylab")
rect(xleft,ybottom,xright,ytop,col=c("blue","red","green"))

#Label position along  axes
x.label.position<-(xleft+xright)/2
y.label.position<-(ybottom+ytop)/2

#Labels
x.label<-c("Long species Name1","Long species Name2","Long species Name3")
y.label<-c("Long species Name4","Long species Name5","Long species Name5")

text(par()$usr[1]-0.5,y.label.position,y.label,xpd=TRUE,adj=1)
text(y=par()$usr[3]-0.5,x=x.label.position,x.label,xpd=TRUE,adj=1,srt=90)

par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(-0.1,0,legend=c("Species A","Species B","Species C"),fill=c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

[image]

Which in reality looks more like this:

[image]

Is there a way to scale the text labels to the width of the squares they represent? Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: So the text is as thin as the boxes? Why bother? They'll be so small as to be just as unreadable as they are when they overlap...

Comment: I agree with @Spacedman, it would be better just to adjust the text so it doesn't overlap.

Comment: Oh, corals, my long lost love! Would it be possible to see your final work?

Comment: If you feel keen to read my dissertation you are more than welcome...although I suspect that wasn't what you were referring too. I do want to publish the data this figure-style will be used to display so I can send you a pdf when it goes to publication :) Thanks for you interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the size using `cex` or its variants (depending on how you add the text), see `?par` for the variants and details.  But for the small ones they are likely to be unreadable (as the comments already state).

An alternative is the `spread.labs` function in the `TeachingDemos` package.

Comment: Thanks. Spread is a nice tool and I will definitely use it in the future. The problem is it is spacing them too evenly. I like the current emphasis on the more abundant species that the space around the labels for the largest boxes gives but I would still like the less abundant species to be visible but not distract attention from the most important and abundant species. Perhaps an inset box with the species with low abundance listed?